# Learning to use Kuberentes on one single computer

Tags: kubernetes

I'm in the need of learning how to use Kubernetes. I've read the first sentences of a couple of introductory tutorials, and never have found one which explains me, step by step, how to build a simulated real world example on a single computer.

Is Kubernetes by nature so distributed that even the 101-level tutorials can only be performed on clusters?

Or can I learn (execute important examples) the important stuff there is to know by just using my Laptop without needing to use a stack of Raspberry Pi's, AWS or GCP?

Comment: Do you mean something like this - https://github.com/infrabricks/kubernetes-standalone

Answer (score 3):

The easiest might be [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube).

> Minikube is a tool that makes it easy to run Kubernetes locally.
>   Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your
>   laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it
>   day-to-day.

For a resource that explains how to use this, try [this getting started guide](https://medium.com/@claudiopro/getting-started-with-kubernetes-via-minikube-ada8c7a29620#.pdmrqs5fb). It runs through an entire example application using a local development environment.

If you are okay with using Google Cloud Platform (I think one gets free credits initially), there is [hello-node](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/).

---

If you want to run the latest and greatest (not necessary stable) and you're using Linux, is also possible to spin up a local cluster on Linux from a cloned copy of the [kubernetes sources](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes), using `hack/local_up_cluster.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out when I find some time during this week. I see that it is still experimental on Windows, which might become problematic. If nothing else comes around, I'll accept this answer.